# how is window created inside iframes? Can I use a modified window object?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to modify how a page reacts to the usage of window elements. Is it possible to use in a newly created iframe the same window object used in parent?

For example if I rewrite `console.lo` to `console.error` in the main console is working fine but not in a newly generated iframe.

So I guess is not using the parent window to build this new one.

Thank you!

EDIT: I did a quick test.

in console.

`console.log = console.error`

`console.log("test");`

output --> test (red error format)

`iframe = document.createElement("iframe");`

`document.body.appendChild(iframe);`

Moving to the iFrame console using chrome developer tools:

`console.log("test")`

output --> test (log format)

Comment: Paste your code here

Comment: @SumeshTG just added an example. Hope it helps understand my problem